# Puppeteer node.js causes memory leak

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I've created a scraper bot that runs once in a hour , and after every run it closes the puppeteer driver completely , What weird is that it shows that the console application I use to run the script at uses just 300mb of ram on peak , (and all the process on the windows around 2gb , while I have 8GB of RAM)
and it says I use 98% of all my memory , There is some kind of memory leak , like something is being cached to the ram , but not displayed anywhere...

Can anybody give me any advice what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: @ThomasDondorf The code is huge and is built pretty much as a Class , Its pretty much Opens a browser every hour , and at the end it does this.browser.close()

Comment: Your code could leak memory anywhere (it could also be Node.js and not puppeteer). Try to debug your code and see which parts of your code are the problem to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @ThomasDondorf Is there any way than Task Manager to check where is all my ram allocated?

Comment: I hope `this.browser.close()` is in a `finally` block. The usual problem here is that the browser object isn't closed on each and every possible path of execution, including all branches and error cases. Voting to close as missing a [mcve] as indicated by Thomas.